# InvalidOperationException while saving a bitmap and using graphics.copyFromScreen parallel-y

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics, bitmap

I am writing an application to capture the screen using the `CopyFromScreen` method, and also want to save the image I capture to send over my local network.
So, I am trying store the captured screen on one bitmap, and save another bitmap, which is the previously captured screen, on two threads.

However, this is throwing an `InvalidOperationException`, which says object is currently in use elsewhere. The exception is thrown by System.Drawing.dll.
    I have tried locking, and am using separate bitmaps for saving and capturing the screen. How do I stop this from happening?  Relevant code:

```
Bitmap ScreenCapture(Rectangle rctBounds)
{
    Bitmap resultImage = new Bitmap(rctBounds.Width, rctBounds.Height);

    using (Graphics grImage = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage))
    {
        try
        {
            grImage.CopyFromScreen(rctBounds.Location, Point.Empty, rctBounds.Size);
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return resultImage;
}

void ImageEncode(Bitmap bmpSharedImage)
{
    // other encoding tasks
    pictureBox1.Image = bmpSharedImage;
    try
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)bmpSharedImage.Clone();
        temp.Save("peace.jpeg");
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 30;
    timer1.Start();
}

Bitmap newImage = null;

private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //take new screenshot while encoding the old screenshot 

    Task tskCaptureTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            newImage = ScreenCapture(_rctDisplayBounds);
        });
    Task tskEncodeTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageEncode((Bitmap)_bmpThreadSharedImage.Clone());
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException err)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(err.Source);
                }
            });

    await Task.WhenAll(tskCaptureTask, tskEncodeTask);

    _bmpThreadSharedImage = newImage;
}
```

[image: img1][image: img2]

Comment: where exactly does it decide something is in use?

Comment: I'm assuming it's `_bmpThreadSharedImage` which you haven't included in the code above that is causing the problem?

Comment: @BugFinder the Exception Unhandled message comes up at `Application.Run(new Form1())` line in Program.cs, and the `CopyFromScreen` and `Bitmap.Save` methods get highlighted

Comment: Take a clone of the image, and then run the task.. (noting you wont need to reclone it)

Comment: @BugFinder That is immediately throwing the same exception

Comment: then it would suggest something else is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a full reproducing code? Difficult to diagnose since important parts of your code don't compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced your problem in a nutshell by creating a simple winforms project with a single button on it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => SomeTask());
    }

    public void SomeTask() //this will result in 'Invalid operation exception.'
    {
        var myhandle = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
        myhandle.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

In order to fix this you need to do the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread myUIthred;

    public Form1()
    {
        myUIthred = Thread.CurrentThread;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => SomeTask());
    }

    public void SomeTask() // Works Great.
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread != myUIthred) //Tell the UI thread to invoke me if its not him who is running me.
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(SomeTask));
            return;
        }
        var myhandle = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
        myhandle.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

The issue is (as Spektre implied) a result of trying to call a UI method from a non-UI thread. The 'BeginInvoke' is actually `this.BeginInvoke' and 'this' is the form which was created by the UI thread and therefore all works.

Answer (score 1):

I do not code in **C#** so I may be wrong here but I assume you are using Windows...

Accessing any visual components (like **GDI Bitmap** or window ...) is not safe outside `WndProc` function. So if you are using **GDI bitmap** (bitmap with device context) or rendering/accessing any visual component from your window inside any thread then there is your problem. After that any call to **WinAPI** in your app can throw an exception (even unrelated to graphics)

So try to move any such code into your `WndProc` function. In case you do not have access to it use any event of your window (like `OnTimer` or `OnIdle`).